# How to remove a last word in the string in Python?

Tags: python, string

For example if I have a string like this:

```
a = "username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello/there"
```

How do I remove the last word after the last `/`. The result should be like this:

```
username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello/ 

OR 

username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello
```

Comment: Since this appears to be a path/url/similar kind of thing, you may want to use an appropriate function (`os.path.split`, etc.) rather than string manipulation.

Comment: You are right. I am looking into os.path.split too. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [6]: a = "username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello/there"

In [7]: a.rpartition('/')[0]
Out[7]: 'username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> "username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello/there".rsplit('/', 1)
['username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello', 'there']
>>> "username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello/there".rsplit('/', 1)[0]
'username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
a = "username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello/there"
print '/'.join(a.split('/')[:-1])
```

Comment: The join is unnecessary and ugly. Using rsplit() is smarter!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most pythonic way but I believe the following would work.

```
tokens=a.split('/')
'/'.join(tokens[:-1])
```

Comment: The join is unnecessary and ugly. Using rsplit() is smarter!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [os.path.dirname](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) ?

```
>>> a = "username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello/there"
>>> import os
>>> os.path.dirname(a)
'username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

a = "username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello/there"
a.rsplit('/', 1)[0]

Result - `username@102.1.1.2:/home/hello/`